# How to code a Google form to add a link to view form submissions with questions

Tags: google-apps-script

I have looked at the Google Apps script how-tos, but it is not self-explanatory to a newbie like me.

I have also tried to adapt online video scripts to what I need and they always return errors.

I need help with how to enter the code below so it generates a link on the form response spreadsheet that shows the complete form with the answers that users submitted.

Below is the code I found on the Google Apps script, but I don't know how to enter it.

`toPrefilledUrl()` generates a URL for the form in which the answers are pre-filled based on the answers in this form response.

```
function addFormResponseUrl(e) {

    // Get the Form response URL and add it to the Google Spreadsheet
    var responseUrl = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl();
    var row = e.range.getRow(1);
    var responseColumn = 1; // Column where the response URL is recorded.
    responseSheet.getRange(row, responseColumn).setValue(responseUrl);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, you mention "below is the code", but there is no code, just a mention of the method `toPrefilledUrl()`. You also mention errors are returned. Which errors?

Comment: Sorry Regina,    I guess i need to know how to enter the method as code. I don't have anything i have personally coded. i found a few scripts online  but they only return errors

Comment: I figured out how to edit to show the code i am trying to adapt

Comment: You question is not quite clear. Where do you want to add the link to? Into the form? Into the spreadsheet that contains the responses? `toPrefilledUrl()` and `getEditResponseUrl()` are two quite different things. Please try to edit your question in such a way that it is easier to understand what your goal is and how to achieve it.

Comment: Ziganotschka,  I would like to get the link to the non editable form that was submitted, to appear in the response spreadsheet.   Sorry about the above code that was my 50 failed attempt to adapt the code  to my needs. thanks again for your time.

Comment: The link to the NON-editable form? I struggle to understand what you mean. Can you explain me how you get this link without Apps Script, from the UI? Apps Script cannot  do what is not possible from the UI.

Comment: I understand, i am probably not using the correct terminology...  What i am looking for is a way to get google apps scripts to add in a link to the response spreadsheet that will allow people to view  user submitted data  in the form view.   I found the code on (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) the method i am looking to use is "toPrefilledUrl()" Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: `toPrefilledUrl()` gives you the URL to the form with default responses, buth those are responses that the form creator set as default, not the ones the user chose and submitted. You can use `getEditResponseUrl()` which allows you to view the actual form that a user submitted, but it would be in such a way that the form can also be modified when following this link. There is no possibility to retrieve a "view only" link wihtout edit permissions. Would `getEditResponseUrl()` be suitable for your purose anyway?

Comment: Yes thank you ,  that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In order to retrieve the `EditResponseUrl` and paste it into the destination spreadsheet next to the form response:

- Write a function that retrieves the latest form response and pastes the respective `EditResponseUrl` into the destination spreadsheet
- Bind the script to the destinaiton spreadsheet
- Attache to the function an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) FormSubmit trigger

Sample script:

```
function addFormResponseUrl(e) {
  //open the form by its id
  var form =FormApp.openById("XXX");
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  // get the latest form response
  var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  //get the response URL
  var responseUrl = lastResponse.getEditResponseUrl();
  // get the sheet where the responses have been stored
  var responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  //get the row where the last response has been stored
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  // Safe the response Url in the first free column after the form responses.
  var responseColumn = e.values.length+1; 
  responseSheet.getRange(row, responseColumn).setValue(responseUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. That worked after i deleted the old triggers.  How do i change the URLs position to column 1 ? On my test form it deletes the answers and put in a url